# Vim: yank to specific register in command-line mode

Tags: vim

I can normally yank like this in the command-line mode `:1,61y`, but how do I yank that to, say, the `"*` (clipboard) register? `:"*1,61y` doesn't work, and `:h c_y` shows nothing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The register name comes after the range and yank portions:

```
:1,61y *
```

See `:h :yank`:

```
:[range]y[ank] [x]      Yank [range] lines [into register x].
```

Comment: I know that is this answer is fairly old, but this is the answer. It took me so long to find this information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just type `"*61yy` while in command mode, you will yank the next 61 lines into the `*` buffer. (Note there is no colon before the command)

Comment: That's useful to know, but don't you mean normal mode?

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me: no, they're not the same. `:help vim-modes`.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger, they are the same; please read `:h vim-modes` again. "command mode" != "command-line mode".

Comment: @romainl I stand corrected, I was unaware of the term *command mode* and misstook it for *command line mode*.